# Error: bad instruction `sync' while corss compiling uboot source with tsec.c driver

Tags: gcc, arm, u-boot

I am trying to compile tsec.c file with the uboot source. I have done that before but with powerpc toolchain. Right now I am trying to use ARM toolchain which comes with android "froyo". Without tsec.c included, uboot compiles fine but when I include this driver, I get following error :-

## //toolchain/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g  -Os   -fno-strict-aliasing  -fno-common -ffixed-r8 -msoft-float  -D_*KERNEL*_ -DTEXT_BASE=0x0F00000 -I/uboot_sapphire/include -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -nostdinc -isystem /home/Build/Android_Froyo/vendor/marvell/generic/toolchain/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/4.2.0/include -pipe  -DCONFIG_ARM -D_*ARM*_ -march=armv5te -mabi=apcs-gnu -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-stack-protector -c -o drivers/net/tsec.o drivers/net/tsec.c

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:31: Error: bad instruction `sync'
{standard input}:73: Error: bad instruction `sync'
{standard input}:79: Error: bad instruction `sync'
{standard input}:402: Error: bad instruction `sync'
{standard input}:2278: Error: bad instruction `sync'
{standard input}:2286: Error: bad instruction `sync'
{standard input}:2293: Error: bad instruction `sync'
```

Can someone help me understanding this error. I tried googling but it dint helped me much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea where you got your tsec.c from so I can't see the source. My best guess is that it has some architecture specific (MIPS) inline assembly.

You'll probably find asm("sync") somewhere in the code.

The error occurs because `sync' is not an arm instruction, so the assembler cannot recognise and assemble it.

To fix the error you will have to port the driver to ARM, which will probably not be a trivial task.

Comment: There is a ethernet driver tsec.c in path drivers/net/tsec.c in uboot source coed. If sync is not an arm instruction then I guess this driver can't be used with arm processors.

Comment: Try getting a more up to date source? This commit http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=commit;h=19d68d202786efe7400dc2a6412c2d06b2ab38ec removed the inline asm, which may well have helped.